# How to use the LSTM layer in PPO architecture?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, long-short-term-memory, actor-critic-methods, proximal-policy-optimization

What is the best way of using the LSTM layer in PPO architecture? 
Should I use them in the first layer of both actor and critic, or use them just before the final layer of these networks? 
Should I feed the architecture with a stack of states (the state stacked with the k previous states)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using TensorFlow-Agents for this, but if you are, there's some nice functionality for this built out using the `ActorDistributionRnnNetwork` and `ValueDistributionRnnNetwork` that I've found to be very helpful.  The LSTM architecture is used in both the actor and critic networks.  See [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/networks/actor_distribution_rnn_network/ActorDistributionRnnNetwork) for more information - hope this helps!